# .net shared variables

Tags: asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have read posts like this: [Is it OK to use static variables to cache information in ASP.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151021/is-it-ok-to-use-static-variables-to-cache-information-in-asp-net).

I am trying to understand the visibility of static variables.  There is one ASP.NET process (W3WP) - I realise that web gardens exist but in my scenario there is one - multiple clients can connect.  If one of those clients set a static (shared) integer to 10 then will all web clients see the Shared variable as 10? I am trying to understand if a Shared variable is like an Application setting or a Session setting.

Does this also apply to VB.NET (client application).  I have read an article, which talks about allowing multiple VB.NET clients to use a single app domain.  Are static variables shared across all clients with a single app domain?

Answer (score 3):

a static / shared variable is per-AppDomain, so *yes* all clients to that AppDomain will see the same value. It is broadly comparable to an application setting, yes.

(Caveat: unless the field is marked `[ThreadStatic]`, but that is a **really** bad idea in a web application.)

You should be **very** cautious of using static / shared fields, especially in a threaded environment. In addition to state bleeding incorrectly between users / sessions, they have inherent thread-safety issues, and you would typically want to synchronize access to them **very** carefully. For example, a static `List<T>` would be really risky if multiple threads can add/remove/etc at the same time.

Comment: Can you confirm that this applies to VB.NET (forms) as well?

Comment: @w0051977: Yes, `Shared` (static) variables are per-AppDomain always, and per-thread if marked `<ThreadStatic()>`.